# How to run a Kafka connect worker in YARN?

Tags: apache-kafka, hadoop-yarn, apache-kafka-connect

I'm playing with [Kafka-Connect](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect). I've got the `HDFS connector` working both in [stand-alone mode](http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/connect/userguide.html#standalone-mode) and [distributed mode](http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/connect/userguide.html#distributed-mode).

They [advertise](http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/connect/design.html#architecture) that the workers (which are responsible for running the connectors) can be managed via `YARN`  However, I haven't seen any documentation that describes how to achieve this goal.

How do I go about getting `YARN` to execute workers?  If there is no specific approach, are there generic how-to's as to how to get an application to run within `YARN`?

I've used `YARN` with SPARK using `spark-submit` however, I cannot figure out how to get the connector to run in `YARN`.

Comment: can you put the `package.json` in your post? maybe it has scripts? and your `yarn.lock`

Comment: I'm not sure you will find lot of info about that. In the ever moving big data tech, Yarn is not so trendy anymore, and many companies rather invest on Mesos scheduling. Anyway for Kafka Connect in Yarn i would probably try https://slider.incubator.apache.org/

Comment: @StephaneMartin I've moved from this project, but thanks for the post, i'll try to check it out...if I do, i'll post my findings here...

Comment: Related post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/confluent-platform/gx6HO8IZu3Y

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can theoretically run anything on YARN, even a simple hello world program. Which is why saying Kafka-Connect runs on YARN is technically correct. The caveat is that getting Kafka-Connect to run on YARN will take a fair amount of elbow grease at the moment. There are two ways to do it:

1. Directly talk to the YARN API to acquire a container, deploy the Kafka-Connect binaries and launch Kafka-Connect.
2. Use the separate Slider project https://slider.incubator.apache.org/docs/getting_started.html that Stephane has already mentioned in the comments.

## Slider

You'll have to read quite a bit of documentation to get it working but the idea behind Slider is that you can get any program to run on YARN without dealing with the YARN API and writing a YARN app master by doing the following:

- Create a slider package out of your program
- Define a configuration for you package
- Use the slider cli to deploy your application onto YARN

Slider handles container deployment and recovery of failed containers for you, which is nice. Also Slider is becoming a native part of YARN when YARN 3.0 is released.

## Alternatives

Also as a side note, getting Kafka-Connect to deploy on Kubernetes or Mesos / Marathon is probably going to be easier. The basic workflow to do that would be:

- Create a Kafka-Connect docker container or just use confluent's [docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect/)
- Create a deployment config for Kubernetes or Marathon
- Click a button / run a command

### Tutorials

- A good Mesos / Marathon tutorial can be found [here](http://www.thedevpiece.com/deploying-and-running-docker-containers-on-marathon/)
- Kubernetes tutorial [here](http://christopher5106.github.io/continous/deployment/2016/05/02/deploy-instantly-from-your-host-to-AWS-EC2-and-Google-Cloud-with-kubernetes.html)
- Confluent Kubernetes Helm Charts [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/cp-helm-charts/docs/index.html)

Comment: Note: YARN 3.0 also supports Docker containers and Slider has been consumed by the core YARN project.